RPI5 hot boot issue
I have a NVME drive via Pi5 pcie extension board. Whenever it is cold, system boots up usually straight away.
However when i try to restart the device, usually it will not restart, and it will stop in stage after RED led goes to Green and FAN starts to spin , and it spins forever and thats how i know it will not start. When i power it off via power button and start again, same thing happens. Same thing when i disconnect power from USBC.
Drive is known to be working, so is the shield. Cables and connections seems to be undamaged. Pi has active cooling fan and shield is mounted at bottom of Pi, not top. Everything is updated.
I am using 5V5A official Rpi newest power supply via USBC. Drive is patriot P300 128GB SSD NVME, cheapest i could find, but new. Wanted to try something cheap before i will put commitement to something more expensive. Nothing other is connected to it besides LAN cable, it is used only remotely.
So far i tried:
Reinstalling system from scratch - did not help.
Putting a 120mm cooling fan in front - did not help ( and it blows really good...)
i tried to add PCIE_PROBE=1 into eeprom config, did not help, and PCIE was run in X2 as well as X3 speed (or is that gen 2 gen 3?)
search for internet for some solutions, but nothing helped so far.
After booting, pi runs fine with no stability and overheating issues for days, drive is "usually hot" as well (nvme drives are generally hot when powered on). I overclocked it to 3GHz, but had same booting difficulties with stock clock as well.
I have no other option to try different PCIE hat, other than to buy another one, but that i want to avoid for as long as possible, because what if another one will have same issues?
Any ideas how to make it boot reliably?

I've used this board without issue (well, one minor one) for several months now. The NVME I used was a Crucial 500GB unit.
